# Spark reduceByKey() to return a compound value

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, reduce

I am new to Spark and stumble upon the following (probably simple) problem.

I have a RDD with key-value elements, each value being a (string, number) pair.
For instance the key-value pair is ('A', ('02', 43)).

I want to reduce this RDD by keeping elements (key and the **whole** value) with maximum numbers when they share the same key.

reduceByKey() seems relevant and i went with this MWE.

```
sc= spark.sparkContext
rdd = sc.parallelize([
 ('A', ('02', 43)),
 ('A', ('02', 36)),
 ('B', ('02', 306)),
 ('C', ('10', 185))])
rdd.reduceByKey(lambda a,b : max(a[1],b[1])).collect()
```

which produces

```
[('C', ('10', 185)), ('A', 43), ('B', ('02', 306))]
```

My problem here is that i would like to get:

```
[('C', ('10', 185)), ('A', ('02', 43)), ('B', ('02', 306))]
```

i.e, i don't see how to return ('A',('02',43)) and not simply ('A',43).

Answer (score 0):

I found myself a solution to this simple problem.
Define a function instead of using an inline function for reduceByKey().
This is:

```
def max_compound(a,b):
 if (max(a[1],b[1])==a[1]):
   return a
 else: 
   return b
```

and call:

```
rdd.reduceByKey(max_compound).collect()
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code is in `Scala`, hope you can convert the same logic into pyspark

```
val rdd = sparkSession.sparkContext.parallelize(Array(('A', (2, 43)), ('A', (2, 36)), ('B', (2, 306)), ('C', (10, 185))))

val rdd2 = rdd.reduceByKey((a, b) => (Math.max(a._1, b._1), Math.max(a._2, b._2)))

rdd2.collect().foreach(println)
```

output:

```
(B,(2,306))
(A,(2,43))
(C,(10,185))
```

Comment: I did not made explicitly clear that i wanted to keep the first pair-element associated to the max number (2nd pair-element). That is ('A', (1, 43)), ('A', (2, 36) would return ('A', (1, 43)). I guess your answer may mix couples, returning in that case (('A', (2,43)).

Comment: @user1551605 to do that you can change the first `max` function to `min` function, that should solve the issue...

Comment: No, this would just work on that example. As said, the general case is to select the pair (u,v) where v is max, whatever u.